# Periodic updates to Access DB in C# over VPN

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vpn

I know this may be considered a generic question, but I honestly don't have the first clue even where to start.  I've tried searching, and have not found any results that fit the application.

I'm trying to develop a front-end for an Access 2010 database that will allow users to add/modify records.  Several of the users use a VPN to connect to the DB, and the current model we are using of an Access 2010 Navigation Form is horrendously slow, regardless of connection speed.  I have verified that we can reach the DB over VPN with no privilege issues or security concerns, but even through the OleDb engine there is significant latency on the data access.

What I would like to do is to be able to have updates sent/received in a background process, say every 5-10 minutes, so that the end user will be able to update it as they need to, and have the changes written without the user really being aware of the latency.  Would simply using a background worker suffice to do this, or is there a better way to send "packets" of updates over the connection?

Again, I know this is not code-specific exactly, but I've never worked with C# and DB updates before, so I'm kind of learning as I go.  Nearly all the results I've found have dealt with engines other than OleDb, such as SQL, but we are locked into using Access (an accdb file) as we don't have any other database engines available to us.  I appreciate any and all help, in whatever form it comes in.

This is a new enough project that so far the only code that I've developed for this has consisted of initializing the connection to the DB to verify that it's even possible.

Comment: What will happen if the connection crashes while there are pending updates in the worker process? (It's a VPN, and people walk around with laptops, this could easily happen.)

Comment: What you're describing is certainly possible, and arguably the right way to do database access in a GUI. But it doesn't mean it won't make your architecture a fair bit more complex. E.g. the solution to the pending update problem I can think of immediately is using a backend service of some sort that would persist the unprocessed transactions using some hopefully reliable way and process them later, like a message queue, which already moves this a bit away from a "learning C# and databases as I go" task.

Comment: (My gut feeling is that getting rid of Access in favour of something that's actually built to handle concurrent users efficiently will be easier than trying to iron out the bugs with delaying writes to an Access file.)

Comment: As for the pending updates, it's not really an issue as we have 2 people that regularly use the VPN as they work from home, the other 2 are in the office on a daily basis.  I do know C# fairly well also, it's the DB aspect of it that I'm relatively new to.  And I would love to dump Access entirely, but I'm not actually IT at my company, this is kind of an "under the radar" situation...it's not disallowed, our IT just tends to be rather territorial.  :)

Comment: With the backend service you refer to, do you mean a backgroup process (ie C# Worker process), or something like a web service?

Comment: By the background service I meant a web service running on / close to the machine where the Access DB is located. The idea is that once the user actually clicks "Save" in a form and thus has reason to believe that his forms have been saved, they should, in fact, be saved **somewhere** where they won't get lost. I.e. not in-memory in another thread.

Comment: You could do that on the local machine and retry pushing them to the DB from there, the backend web service seems like a better option to me though. Mostly because it lets you get rid of concurrent access to the Access DB, which seems to be the root cause of your problems. Only the backend web service would ever have the database file open, locally to itself.

Comment: Have you investigated using any remote access options (e.g., Terminal Services, Remote Desktop, LogMeIn, etc.)?

Answer (score -2):

MS Access is not designed to be concurrent.  When you open access db on remote machine you also downloading the entire db onto the client machine memory that's why the bigger the file the more it become slower.. If you wished to make it concurrent use MS SQL Express and linked it to your MS Access application.  This way it is much faster and better.

Beside its free, and can be upscale if you needed.

Comment: You may download it here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: -1 While I agree that for a slow WAN/VPN connection using a SQL Server back-end would probably be better than using an Access back-end, the statements *"MS Access is not designed to be concurrent."* and *"When you open access db on remote machine you also downloading the entire db onto the client machine memory"* are both patently false.